# DENSE_RANK() OVER (Order by UniqueIdentifer) issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, dense-rank, sql-order-by

I'm struggling trying to get DENSE_RANK to do what I want it to do.

It is basically to create a unique invoice number based on a unique identifier, but it needs to go up in order based on the date/time of the invoice.

For example I need:

```
InvoiceNo                  TxnId                     TxnDate
    1       6C952E91-B888-4244-9079-14FBECAE0BA2    01/01/2014 00:01
    1       6C952E91-B888-4244-9079-14FBECAE0BA2    01/01/2014 00:02
    1       6C952E91-B888-4244-9079-14FBECAE0BA2    01/01/2014 00:03
    1       6C952E91-B888-4244-9079-14FBECAE0BA2    01/01/2014 00:04
    1       6C952E91-B888-4244-9079-14FBECAE0BA2    01/01/2014 00:05
    1       6C952E91-B888-4244-9079-14FBECAE0BA2    01/01/2014 00:06
    1       6C952E91-B888-4244-9079-14FBECAE0BA2    01/01/2014 00:07
    1       6C952E91-B888-4244-9079-14FBECAE0BA2    02/01/2014 00:08
    2       8A5BCC36-8A70-4BE1-9FAB-A33BDD5BB78F    02/02/2014 00:09
    2       8A5BCC36-8A70-4BE1-9FAB-A33BDD5BB78F    02/02/2014 00:09
    3       83168B53-1647-4EB9-AF17-0B285EAA69B4    03/03/2014 00:10
    3       83168B53-1647-4EB9-AF17-0B285EAA69B4    03/03/2014 00:20
    3       83168B53-1647-4EB9-AF17-0B285EAA69B4    03/03/2014 00:21
    3       83168B53-1647-4EB9-AF17-0B285EAA69B4    03/03/2014 00:23
```

But what I get when using DENSE_RANK OVER (Order by TxnId) is:

```
InvoiceNo       TxnId                                 TxnDate
    1       6C952E91-B888-4244-9079-14FBECAE0BA2    01/01/2014 00:02
    1       6C952E91-B888-4244-9079-14FBECAE0BA2    01/01/2014 00:01
    1       6C952E91-B888-4244-9079-14FBECAE0BA2    01/01/2014 00:03
    1       6C952E91-B888-4244-9079-14FBECAE0BA2    01/01/2014 00:04
    1       6C952E91-B888-4244-9079-14FBECAE0BA2    01/01/2014 00:06
    1       6C952E91-B888-4244-9079-14FBECAE0BA2    01/01/2014 00:05
    1       6C952E91-B888-4244-9079-14FBECAE0BA2    02/01/2014 00:08
    1       6C952E91-B888-4244-9079-14FBECAE0BA2    01/01/2014 00:07
    2       83168B53-1647-4EB9-AF17-0B285EAA69B4    03/03/2014 00:10
    2       83168B53-1647-4EB9-AF17-0B285EAA69B4    03/03/2014 00:21
    2       83168B53-1647-4EB9-AF17-0B285EAA69B4    03/03/2014 00:20
    2       83168B53-1647-4EB9-AF17-0B285EAA69B4    03/03/2014 00:23
    3       8A5BCC36-8A70-4BE1-9FAB-A33BDD5BB78F    02/02/2014 00:09
    3       8A5BCC36-8A70-4BE1-9FAB-A33BDD5BB78F    02/02/2014 00:09
```

If I do DENSE_RANK OVER(TxnId,TxnDate), it is a complete mess and doesn't do what I want either.

Any ideas guys? Am I even using the write function to do this? Any help appreciated :)

Comment: Do you want `ROW_NUMBER` instead of `DENSE_RANK`?

Comment: No, Row_Number would do 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 for the Invoice number regardless of the invoice, I need 1 unique invoice number per TxnId, but ordered by the date.

Comment: no, you can use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition By TxnId Order by TxnDate)`

Comment: That is what I did. This then counts up based on how many instances of the same TxnId there is. i.e. if there are 3 instances of that same transaction ID, each one will have a unique number, which is incorrect. It needs to be unique by TxnId, so 1 TxnId = 1 Invoice Number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want:

```
select dense_rank() over (order by txnid, txndate)
```

Everything with the same transaction id *and* date will have the same value.

EDIT:

If you need to extract the date, then that depends on the database.  It would look something like this.  For Oracle:

```
select dense_rank() over (order by txnid, trunc(txndate))
```

For Postgres:

```
select dense_rank() over (order by txnid, date_trunc('day', txndate))
```

For SQL Server:

```
select dense_rank() over (order by txnid, cast(txndate as date))
```

EDIT II:

You want the transactions ordered by the earliest date.  Get the earliest date and then do the `dense_rank()`:

```
select dense_rank() over (order by txnmindate, txnid)
from (select t.*, min(txndate) over (partition by txnid) as txnmindate
      from table t
     ) t
```

Comment: No Dense_Rank() over (Order by TxnId,TxnDate) won't work as the date is different per line of the TxnId. I will edit the original to show this.

Comment: Doesn't seem to make any difference at all, and if there was a transaction that rolls over to the following day it wouldn't work either. Using SQL Server by the way.

Comment: @Adam'Yoko'Chapman . . . This answers the question that you asked.  If you have a different question, such as transactions spanning multiple days and rules for determining whether they get a new invoice id, then ask another question with the appropriate details.

Comment: The example specified spans over multiple days on the first TxnId, probably not too clear though.